# Hosting from my computer - This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode. Abyss web server

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, publish, asp.net-mvc-5, remote-server

I tried hosting ASP MVC 5 on the Abyss Web server and this is the error it gave me:

> This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

Is there any work a rounds? And is this the right program to be hosting MVC 5 on from my computer?

Comment: What is an Abyss Web Server? Also are you using MVC `5.1`?

Comment: Nope, 5.0 .. How would I upgrade that? And Abyss is just to turn my computer into a remote network. Which is what I am trying to do and then host my mvc 5 project on it. Got any suggestions ? Cheers.

Comment: Ok..so you are still using IIS I believe...Make sure your application's app pool is set to use `Integrated` mode and the .net version to be 4.0

Comment: @Kiran Yes, that's right. I completely agree with Kiran answer, please make sure you change your app pool to integrated. Please check it on IIS--> app pool--> your domain--> properties--> find it. :)

Comment: Aprelium's Abyss web server is not IIS.  Unfortunately, I am having the same problem.